# How can I insert two variables into a table, when one has one value, and the other has multiple values?

Tags: mysql, sql

For future reference:
In my database all associative entities have the "$" character in them.
For example the "property_type$question" table associates my "property_type" table and my "question" table.

I'm creating this stored procedure to generate surveys for a given property:

```
/*---------- PROCEDURE TO GENERATE SURVEY FOR A PROPERTY ----------*/
        DELIMITER //
        CREATE PROCEDURE GenerateSurvey (IN input_property_id INT)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO survey (checksum_xxx, cas_id)
            VALUES
            (123, 'CAS-XXX-YYYY');

            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @last_survey_id;

            INSERT INTO property$survey (property_id, survey_id)
            VALUES
            (input_property_id, @last_survey_id);

            SELECT property_type$question.question_id
            INTO @survey_questions
            FROM (
                SELECT property.id AS 'property_id',
                property_type.id AS 'property_type_id'
                FROM property JOIN property_type
                ON property.property_type_id = property_type.id
                WHERE property.id = input_property_id
            ) AS subquery join property_type$question
            ON subquery.property_type_id = property_type$question.property_type_id
            WHERE subquery.property_id = input_property_id;

            INSERT INTO survey$question$answer (survey_id, question_id)
            VALUES
            (@last_survey_id, @survey_questions);
        END //
        DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting this error:
[image]

I suspect this error is happening at the last INSERT of my stored procedure, when inserting into the `survey$question$answer` table.

It returns an error because `@last_survey_id` contains a single survey id, but `@survey_questions` contains multiple question ids.

I want to insert multiple rows in the `survey$question$answer` table.

Every row should have the same `survey_id` (stored in `@last_survey_id`), but each row should have a different value for `question_id` (stored in `@survey_questions`).

For example:
If to a survey with an ID of 2, belong the questions with IDs 4, 5 and 6, I would want it to look like:

survey_id | question_id
    2     |     4
    2     |     5
    2     |     6

However, not every survey has the same number of questions.
This means I can't really use an insert with a format of:

```
INSERT INTO survey$question$answer (survey_id, question_id)
VALUES
    (@last_survey_id, @survey_questions);
    (@last_survey_id, @survey_questions);
    (@last_survey_id, @survey_questions);
```

Because there is no way to know how many questions the survey will have.

So survey 3 might have the questions 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50.
This should result in:

survey_id | question_id
    3     |     10
    3     |     20
    3     |     30
    3     |     40
    3     |     50

So how do I go through all the values in `@survey_questions`, and insert a row for each different value, and then at the same time insert the same value (in `@last_survey_id`) for every row?

Would this work better if I just did them separately?
Maybe first insert all the `question_id`s, and then update the rows to include the same `survey_id` for each row? I'm having trouble figuring out how I would even do this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the error is generated because you try to store multiple values in one scalar variable. Instead of using a variable `@survey_questions` to fetch into, you can directly insert the result of the query into the table.

Remove the last `SELECT` and the last `INSERT` and put:

```
INSERT INTO survey$question$answer
            (survey_id,
             question_id)
            SELECT @last_survey_id,
                   property_type$question.question_id
                   FROM (SELECT property.id property_id,
                                property_type.id property_type_id
                                FROM property
                                     INNER JOIN property_type
                                                ON property.property_type_id = property_type.id
                                WHERE property.id = input_property_id) subquery
                        INNER JOIN property_type$question
                                   ON subquery.property_type_id = property_type$question.property_type_id
                        WHERE subquery.property_id = input_property_id;
```